# Android Play store app rejected update possibly due to removed permisstion

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

Hello all please help me to solve below issue 
I've uploaded an APK and into permission declaration form i have clicked SMS and call permission granted now i've removed those permission. and app get rejected my update. I've tried to upload new update with permission also but not worked. can you please guide me thanks in advance is possible to fill permission form again? please provide me help!!!!!!!!!!!
I got The

> 1. Play Console may still be prompting you to submit a Permissions
>      Declaration Form if you still have active APKs in different tracks.
>      If you have active APKs with permissions in multiple tracks, you
>      have to submit Permissions Declaration Forms in each track’s
>      releases except for the last one and you will not be asked to submit
>      Permissions Declaration Form in your last release. You can also
>      deactivate or create an empty release (a release without any APKs)
>      for testing tracks as part of this.
>          Charlotte5:39 PM
>          To release a new compliant APK, please follow these steps:
>          Go to your Play Console.
>          Select the app.
>          On the left menu, select Release management > App releases.
>          Next to the release track(s) where non-compliant APK(s) are in active status, select Manage.
>          Highly recommended to make your last release in production track if your production track has non-compliant APK.
>          Suggested order (if tracks have non-compliant APKs): Internal track > Closed > Open > Production
>          To create a new release, select Create release (or Edit release).
>          Upload a new compliant APK or ‘Add from library’ 
>          If you see the Permissions Declaration Form while releasing the app, please complete the form according to the following
>      instructions:
>          Choose one core functionality(e.g. Default SMS handler) to make a release with compliant APK. This release may automatically lead
>      to
>      rejection but this will deactivate the non-compliant APK(s) in the
>      track.
>          Select Save > Review at the bottom of the page.
>          Click Start Rollout. 
>          Please ensure that the new release is rolled out 100% and completely deactivates the non-compliant APK. 
>          Go back to step 1 to make another release in the track where non-compliant APK(s) are in active status until there is no active
>      APK with sensitive permissions across tracks.

But i am not getting If you see the Permissions Declaration Form while releasing the app, please complete the form according to the following instructions: anywhere

Comment: Do you have any APK in your alpha or beta release, Maybe the reason to reject because you update release but if you are not updating in beta or alpha then also google will reject your app.

Comment: @Dhaval Solanki there is no APK in alpha or beta

Comment: Okay,  This is the possibility

Comment: @Dhaval Solanki another any way?

Answer (score 0):

check the manifest file it still has that permission, for a confirmation you can generate a release build and decompile it or install it on a device and go to settings where you can see that permission,
its because android does update the changes you made on the manifest.xml so you can change the permission in merged  manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

[manifest image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VKkm.png)

goto this section in manifest then find the permission you need to change